# dataset not 'callable' in a for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop, dataset, mnist

Trying to work with a model for a custom dataset. The model was based on MNIST and had a for loop that does

```
for images,labels in train_dataset():
```

The issue with this is I have tried to set my training_dataset as numpy arrays, iterators and everything else. But I always get a ....

```
object is not callable
```

error. I think it is because MNIST is seen as a dataset V1 adapter. So how do I convert.

Or else I need to do a

```
for images, labels in X,y:
```

or something similar

Comment: `train_dataset()` is not a function, you cant do `()` on it. is it a list? an array? a dict?something else? try without the `()`

Comment: what is `train_dataset()`?

Comment: train dataset is the list/iterator that I am using for my dataset. My guess is that the code I found is working on a dataset adapter

Comment: I tried without the brackets just now. I get a too many values to unpack (expected 2) error